# Multi dimensional input multi dimensional output rnn keras data preprocessing

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create a RNN model in Keras. In each time-step the input has 9 element and the output has 4 element.

```
input_size = (304414,9)
target_size = (304414,4)
```

How can I create a dataset of sliding windows over the time-series.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code by considering windows size and stride

```
for idx in range(0, input.shape[0] - window_size - 1, stride):
        input.append(input_data[idx + 1: idx + 1 + window_size, :])

    input = np.reshape( input, (len(input), input[0].shape[0], input[0].shape[1]))
```